# How to change numpy.array sample rate?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say, I've got a signal which is one dimensional numpy array lasting for one second with sample rate equal to 16 kHz. How can I resample this array for instance to 1024 Hz without loosing information about "peaks" present in this signal as shown below? I add only that intervals between "peaks" are not less, than 40 ms.

UPDATE

I've found an interesting approach based on `scipy.signal.resample` function, but the problem with this function is that it return absolute value for each `y` value of the given vector.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a signal processing question.

Comment: You may find a answer over at dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I completely disagree with your assessment of the topic inappropriateness. This is straightly implementation problem, not teoretical issue.

Comment: It sounded like you wanted a method of downsampling that preserves the peak information - that doesn't sound like a coding question. You could look on the code for ```scipy.signal.resample``` and find where the sign information is lost and try to remedy it, creating your own function based on the original.

Comment: It's unclear what's being asked though as, "information about 'peaks' present in this signal as shown below" requires a lot of interpretation, and I have no idea what the OP really wants (and I assume they don't either). All time slots in a signal carry information, even if they have a zero value, so the premiss has no answer, but beyond this, there are still many details left out.  Instead, people will need to guess at what might be acceptable solutions, and that makes it a question that should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `scipy`, I suggest [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html).

However also `numpy` has a 1D interpolation in [`numpy.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), so that might just be what you want.

For what you are asking (not loosing the peaks), that is a bit of an ill posed problem, that can't be solved by a simple and naîve interpolation.

**My 2 cents solution:** Since you are downsampling, and you know the downsampling ratio, you can just extend the peaks so to not lose them after downsampling, i.e. so that the peak duration in the downsampled signal is **at least** one sample, that is, is at least `ceil(SR1/SR2)` samples before downsampling, where `SR1` is the original sample rate, and `SR2` is the downsampled rate..

Answer (score 0):

Plain resampling will always loose some information. If the height of the peaks is important, but not so much width, you could just take 1 every 16 samples (given that the peaks are at least 16 samples wide at 16kHz).

If you have few peaks, you could consider a far better algorithm: Just record the time instant and delta, for each change. In your diagram (estimated):

```
21050 +2000
21060 -2000
24030 -500
24040 +500
26030 +1000
26040 -1000
```

This will surely occupy much less than sampling. In just 6 values (which could be stored in binary) I compressed your data.